# Timeout jobs on sun grid engine

Tags: timeout, sungridengine

I'm running a lot of jobs with sun grid engine (linux). Some of the jobs take a (very) long time to run, and I don't know ahead which ones.

I would like to stop jobs that run for more than, say, 2 hours. Is it possible to run using SGE? Is it possible to do it from the unix shell?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running the jobs yourself then use the hard wall clock time.

#$ -l h_rt=2:00:00

Where time is hr:min:sec

Comment: any pointers to the man page please